# Adding subtotals to pivot_table using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table, subtotal

I'm trying to include subtotals in my pivot_table.

Pivot table code

```
# Specify the aggregation functions
aggfunc = {'amt': 'sum', 'llp': 'first'}
```

Pivot and calculate aggregated values using aggfunc

```
Pivoted_data = pd.pivot_table(pivot_data,index=['Expense', 'Name', 'Currency', 'Facility'],values= ["amt", "llp"], aggfunc= aggfunc, dropna=True)
```

I have this code which works but my output is creating a long string rather than separate columns for each of the indexes.

````
sub = pd.concat([d.append(d.sum().rename((k,'Total')))
for k, d in pivoted_data.groupby(level=0)])
.append(pivoted_data.sum().rename(('Grand','Total'))) ```
````

How can I have it so the indexes aren't merged together as a list in one cell when exporting to excel?

So I want this:

| Expense | Name | Currency | Name | Amt | LLP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Xy | Eur | Xyz | 7059 | 0 |
| A Total |  |  |  | 7059 | 0 |
| B | Zz | GBP | Xyzs | 5803 | 50 |
| B | Z2z | GBP | Xyzs123 | 9586 | 6000 |
| B Total |  |  |  | 15389 | 6050 |

But my code is giving me this.

|  | Amt | LLP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A, Xy, Eur,Xyz | 7059 | 0 |
| A Total |  |  | 7059 |
| B, Zz, GBP, Xyzs | 5803 | 50 |
| B, Z2z, GBP, Xyzs123 | 9586 | 6000 |
| B Total |  |  | 15389 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `MultiIndex` with `4 levels`, so added tuples with all values, because `append` is deprecated solution use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
sub = pd.concat([pd.concat([d, d.sum().rename((f'{k} Total','','','')).to_frame().T]) 
                 for k, d in pivoted_data.groupby(level=0)] + 
                [pivoted_data.sum().rename((f'Grand Total','','','')).to_frame().T])
print (sub)
                                     Amt   LLP
Expense     Name Currency Name.1              
A           Xy   Eur      Xyz       7059     0
A Total                             7059     0
B           Zz   GBP      Xyzs      5803    50
            Z2z  GBP      Xyzs123   9586  6000
B Total                            15389  6050
Grand Total                        22448  6050
```